# Updating a like on a post in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to write a view in django (DRF) that allows users to add a like on a post, update the like state (like/dislike) on the post and delete the like on a post. The post ID is sent in the paramters and the user ID is extracted from the auth token.

I figured out how to do the first two but I can't figure out how to do the update. Here's what I have so far in my view:

```
class LikeView(generics.CreateAPIView, UpdateModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin):
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer
    queryset = Like.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'post'
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_object(self):
        post = self.request.query_params.get('post')
        user = self.request.user.id
        return self.get_queryset().filter(post=post, user=user)

    # retrieve user ID from token, validate data and save the like on post (working)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = self.get_data(request)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response('Like has been saved')

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = self.get_data(request)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

    # working
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # add the data from param and token to a copy of the request body 
    # to use with the serializers
    def get_data(self, request):
        data = request.data.copy()
        data['post'] = self.request.query_params.get('post')
        data['user'] = request.user.id
        return data
```

Like model:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = BooleanField(
        default=True, help_text='Like = True, Dislike = False')
    created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        state_int = int(self.state)
        return ['Dislike', 'Like'][state_int]

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'post')
```

What am I doing wrong here? What is missing the `put` handler?

Comment: Can you show your models?

Comment: Added the like model.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed providing **`instance`** parameter to the ***`serializer`*** in the **`put`** method.

```
class LikeView(generics.CreateAPIView, UpdateModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin):
    # other code

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = self.get_data(request)
        like_instance = Like.objects.get(user=request.user, post_id=int(data['post']))  # you should include 'post' while making PUT requests
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance=like_instance, data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response('Your response')
```

Comment: So you imply that `instance` is a Post, but at the same time you pass this object to the `get_serializer` method on a `View` that has `LikeSerializer` as a serializer? That's pure insanity right there.

Comment: @VsevolodTImchenko That was my mistake... It should the **`Like`** instance instead of **`Post`**. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't return any value from this method.

```py
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = self.get_data(request)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
```

Try to add

```py
        return Response('Like has been updated')
```

Second, you need to pass the instance to the serializer:

```py
        data = self.get_data(request)
        instance = self.get_queryset().get(user_id=request.user.id, post_id=request.data['post_id'])
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance=instance, data=data)
```

If it doesn't work, report what exactly isn't working.